# JavaScript / jQuery mouseover event with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mouseover

I have a code that allows me to show hidden divs after a little delay on mouseover, my problem now is that im not very good with CS, i have elements in that div with that code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var timer;
  var delay = 250;
  $("#content1").mouseover(function() {
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      $("#content.left1").css("display", "block");
    }, delay);
  });
  $("#content1").mouseout(function() {
    $("#content.left1").css("display", "none");
    clearTimeout(timer);
  });
});
```

```css
.txtmiddle {
  border: 1px solid rgba(215, 215, 215, 0.1);
  background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.7);
  margin-top: 5px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
  padding: 2%;
  border-radius: 15px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.1s;
  animation: fadeIn 0.1s;
}
.txtmiddle:hover {
  border: 1px solid rgba(55, 55, 55, 0.2);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
#content {
  display: none;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
#txtleft {
 width: 30%;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 4%;
 border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
}
```

```html
  <div id="txtleft"><div id="content" class="left1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
  sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit a</div>  </div>
  <div id="middlewrapper"><div class="txtmiddle" id="content1">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Nuvola_mimetypes_info.png/100px-Nuvola_mimetypes_info.png" id="midcontentleft">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Nuvola_mimetypes_info.png/100px-Nuvola_mimetypes_info.png" id="midcontentimgright" class="1">
</div>  </div>
```

cant get it to run here.... but its working fine my only problem is now that everytime i hover over elements (those images) in the div the hidden content is (re-)shown again (with that delay) (before i didnt had the delay so the hidden element wouldnt disapear and apear again and one couldnt notice the change...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As correctly said by atinder fadeIn and fadeOut functions of jQuery will serve your need:

Try the below code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var delay = 1000;//the delay interval
jQuery("#content1").mouseover(function() {     
  jQuery( "#content.left1" ).fadeIn(delay);
});
jQuery("#content1").mouseout(function() {    
   jQuery( "#content.left1" ).fadeOut(delay);
   });
});
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: @UdSSR Not sure why this has been marked as the accepted answer when it doesn't address the question?

Comment: It has being marked as accepted answer since it exactly fulfills the request of the question...!

Comment: The question states that the issue is to do with the content being reloaded as you hover over the div, which your solution doesn't fix?

Comment: The question is solve the issue "element disappear and appear again but one couldn't notice the change" . The solution of mine resolves the issue :)

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the question. The OP does not want the transition effect to be noticable when hovering over the images within the div.

Answer (score 2):

why not simply use `fadeIn('slow')` and `fadeOut('slow')` instead

Comment: i try now     `$("#content1").mouseover(function () {$("#content.left1").fadeIn('slow') } );
    $("#content1").mouseout(function(){ $("#content.left1").fadeOut('slow') });` but the content is fading in instantly and fading out takes like 3 seconds...

Answer (score 2):

I would usually use [jQuery hover()](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) to achieve what you are looking for:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var timeout;

    $("#content1").hover(function () {
        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            $("#content.left1").css("display", "block");
        }, 250);
    },
    function () {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        $("#content.left1").css("display", "none");
    });
});
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sh72quqo/).